# How to remove the automatic table title from kable table in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

I currently have a R Markdown file where I have some table exporting to LaTex with the `knitr` package and the `kable()`  function. The problem is that when I knit, there is some automatic titles add to my tables such as :

**Table 1: My Title**

When I would like to have :

**My title**

Here is a sample of my code :

```
kable(import_data, "latex", longtable = T, caption = "Description of Data") 
%>% kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "repeat_header")))
```

Even if my title is correct, the output will be `Table 1: Description of Data`.

Anyone can help me with this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be quite useful when you have a lot of table to avoid the automatic `Table 1:` on all of your LaTex table in R Markdown. I suggest you use this code :

`\usepackage[labelformat = empty]{caption}`

I personnally simply add this code to a `.sty` file that I import into R. You can also add it directly into your R Setup. This will give you the output you are looking for :

Caption : `Description of Data`.

Tell me if that's work for you.

**Note :** I know this is working very well for LaTex/PDF table with `kable()` but I guess it is also working with  the LaTex/HTML table too.